# How do you make a UIViewController background look like the background of a grouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

sorry this is probably a dumb question, but I want to make the background of a normal UIViewController look like the gray, pinstriped background that of a grouped UITableView. Is this possible. Tell me if you need pictures, and I'll post some. Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the view controller's view's background color to `groupTableViewBackgroundColor`

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to work on the iPad (or at least I haven't been able to get it to work as such)

Comment: I am having the same issue on the iPad, does not seem to work.  Anyone found an answer?

Comment: I submitted a bug report on this, and the wrote back saying this is the desired behaviour. On the iPad, the table view background color is clear, but the it's superview's color is that color you see. [UIColor colorWithRed:0.821 green:0.834 blue:0.860 alpha:1] is accurate for the iPad.